# Vue.js 2.7, "script setup"-approach, defineEmits with composable which needs a emit-function

Tags: vuejs2, typescript-typings, vue-composition-api

I am using `Vue.js 2.7`, I have a (probably TS-only) issue with `defineEmits` and a self-written composable which needs an `emit-function` to pass in. The self-written composable should replace a Mixin and is actually too complex, but that's not the problem a like to ask about.

The following does **not** work.

**vue**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineEmits } from 'vue'; // <- removing this import has no effect
import { useIcomActCompatibility } from '@/composables/compatibility/useIcomActCompatibility';
import { ApiCallParameterType } from '@/services/ApiService';
import { ApiContacts_ListType } from '@/store/types/api/events';

const emit = defineEmits({
    'i-do-nothing'(): boolean {
        return true;
    },
});

const { apiId /* TODO add other necessary stuff */ } = useIcomActCompatibility<
    'contacts',
    ApiContacts_ListType,
    'List'
>({
    usedApiId: 'contacts',
    usedApiUrl: '/configuration/events/contacts',
    usedDataByIdStorePath: 'apiEvents/getApiDataById',
    emit, // <- TS2322
    sendApiRequest: (_p: ApiCallParameterType): Promise<boolean> => (
        console.log('calling dummy sendApiRequest'), Promise.resolve(true)
    ),
});
</script>
```

**TS2322** is:

```
Type '(event: 'i-do-nothing') => void' is not assignable to type '(event: string, ...args: any[]) => void'.
Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type ''i-do-nothing''.
```

The code (Vue component) above, beside the `TS-Error`, could not be created.

Well so far. If I change the code like this?

**Vue**

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, Ref } from 'vue';
import { useIcomActCompatibility } from '@/composables/compatibility/useIcomActCompatibility';
import { ApiCallParameterType, ApiDataType } from '@/services/ApiService';
import { ApiContacts_ListType } from '@/store/types/api/events';

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'HttpServerAct',

    setup(props, { emit }): { apiId: Ref<keyof ApiDataType> } {
        const { apiId /* TODO add other necessary stuff */ } = useIcomActCompatibility<
            'contacts',
            ApiContacts_ListType,
            'List'
        >({
            usedApiId: 'contacts',
            usedApiUrl: '/configuration/events/contacts',
            usedDataByIdStorePath: 'apiEvents/getApiDataById',
            emit,
            sendApiRequest: (_p: ApiCallParameterType): Promise<boolean> => (
                console.log('calling dummy sendApiRequest'), Promise.resolve(true)
            ),
        });
        return { apiId };
    },
});
</script>
```

Everything works. My expectation was/is that the 1. version should work also.

What am I doing wrong? I can't imagine that the TS error is solely responsible for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `defineEmits` should look like this:

```
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'i-do-nothing'): boolean;
}>();
```

https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-emits

Comment: Thank you Kuban, your are right.